# How to use Maven command with accent in directory name on Jenkins pipeline and Docker?

Tags: docker, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I do not understand why it works locally (Windows 10) when it does not work on my Jenkins which uses Docker on unix.

```
withMaven(globalMavenSettingsConfig: 'empty-global-settings', mavenSettingsConfig: Constants.CONFIG_SETTINGS_ID) {
    sh "pwd"
    sh "ls -lrt"
    sh "ls -lrt /home/jenkins/workspace/myProject"
    sh "ls -lrt /home/jenkins/workspace/myProject/règles"
    sh "$MVN_CMD deploy -X"
}
```

and my result is:

```
+ ls -lrt /home/jenkins/workspace/myProject
total 8
drwxr-xr-x. 2 jenkins root  125 Jul 15 21:32 bom
-rw-r--r--. 1 jenkins root  657 Jul 15 21:32 assembly.xml
drwxr-xr-x. 3 jenkins root   27 Jul 15 21:32 ressources
-rw-r--r--. 1 jenkins root 1492 Jul 15 21:32 pom.xml
drwxr-xr-x. 2 jenkins root   57 Jul 15 21:32 data
drwxr-xr-x. 3 jenkins root   23 Jul 15 21:32 règles
drwxr-xr-x. 3 jenkins root   82 Jul 15 21:32 target
[Pipeline] sh
+ ls -lrt $'/home/jenkins/workspace/myProject/r\303\250gles'
total 0
```

**total 0** but my folder `règles` is not empty

**EDIT:**

I try with `mavenOpts`:

```
withMaven(globalMavenSettingsConfig: 'empty-global-settings', mavenSettingsConfig: Constants.CONFIG_SETTINGS_ID, mavenOpts: '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8') {
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I change my Docker image and it works.